# MongoDB mapReduce per minute document count segregated by an additional category field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, nosql

I have a MongoDB collection with the following schema:

```
const MessageSchema = {
 message: {type: String},
 category: {type String, allowedValues: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']},
 createdAt: {type: Date}
}
```

These message documents are created at random time intervals. I'd like to create the dataset needed for a chart that plots the number of messages per minute (count) for each category. The output would be an array of objects with keys `time, a.count, b.count, c.count, d.count` and `e.count`. The resulting dataset shall only consider data from the last week, and not further back.

The dataset can be pretty large.

I think I can do this with `db.collection.mapReduce`. I found a solution that works for all the messages, but not separated by category. A pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at aggregation? $group?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use mapReduce when you can do this with a simple aggregation:

```
db.messages.aggregate([
  {$match: { createdAt: { $gte: ISODate('2018-01-01') } }},
  {$group: {
        _id: {date: {$dateFromParts:{
                year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
                month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" },
                hour: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" },
                minute: { $minute: "$createdAt" }
             }},
             category: "$category"
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MongoDB Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for this by matching on records that have occurred after `createdAt` then grouping by `category`:

```
db.getCollection('messages').aggregate([{
        $match: { createdAt: { $gte: ISODate('2018-10-10') } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
                day: { $dayOfYear: "$createdAt" },
                minute: { $minute: "$createdAt" },
            },
            categories: { $push: "$category" }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$categories" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { interval: "$_id", category: "$categories" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.interval",
            category_count: {
                $push: { category: "$_id.category", count: "$count" }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: How do I then create the counts per minute interval?  Do I feed the output of the aggregation function into mapReduce? Thanks for the quick answer.